# Should I replace my tire because of this cut on the sidewall?

Tags: tires

During the maintenance they found this cut on the sidewall of my tire. My car just passed the APK in the Netherlands, which is similar to MOT in UK, which checks damages on tires. So legally it's still ok to drive, but I am wondering if it already impact the safety?

[image: See picture]

Comment: This will question will probably be closed due to its nature, but bring it to a tire store. They will accurately tell you it's unsafe to drive on. The side of the tire is the most vulnerable part of the tire when damaged.

Comment: Presumably it happened after the APK test. In UK the MOT test does not and cannot guarantee the vehicle is safe for one year. It's just a legally required check that the vehicle is safe ***at the time it was tested***. You say *So legally it's still ok to drive*. In UK it is not legal to drive a vehicle that would fail an MOT test. There is no kind of immunity conferred, and it is illegal to drive an unroadworthy vehicle. Just as a simple example, the tyres may have a legal amount of tread when tested, but not 6 months later.